# Travelling to the Middle East through Vienna and Frankfurt from Canada, holding Canadian PR

Tags: international-travel, transit-visas, connecting-flights, iranian-citizens

I am a Canadian permanent resident / Iranian citizen. I am flying from Canada to the Middle East through Europe. I have 2 stops in Europe. The first one is in Frankfurt and the second one in Vienna. I do not hold a transit visa.

Will I be able to connect through these 2 airports to my destination without a need for a visa?

Comment: Two airports in a row within Schengen, you need a Schengen visa.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The flight from Frankfurt to Vienna is within the Schengen Zone and is considered a domestic flight. You'll need to pass through Customs and Immigration at Frankfurt and reclaim your baggage before checking in and  boarding your onward flight.

Since you're an Iranian citizen entering the Schengen area you will need a Schengen 'C' visa which you should apply for at the nearest German consulate to you. [Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/transit-schengen-visa/)

Comment: What makes you think that they need to collect their luggage at any of the transit stops?

Comment: They're entering the Schengen zone from a third country and will need to pass through customs and immigration at Frankfurt. Are you suggesting they can do that without their baggage?

Comment: What makes you think they need to pass through customs in the first place? Usually their baggage would be checked through, and they would not leave the airside transfer area. They _would_ leave the non-Schengen area and pass through immigration -- but if their itineray is on one booking I see no reason why they would need _also_ to collect luggage and pass _customs_.